# Change the font of letters, but not numbers, in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, pdftex

I have been looking for a way to let me change the font style of only Latin letters, but not numbers, etc., in math mode in pdflatex.

To illustrate what I mean: `$\mysf E = mc^2$` would be equivalent to `$\sf E = mc^{\rm 2}$` or `${\sf E = mc}^2$`.

I know that in xelatex one can specify the individual character ranges when applying an external font, but is there any way to do it simply with `\sf` in pdflatex?

Comment: The command `\sf` has been deprecated for about 30 years.

Comment: @egreg That's fair, I didn't know. In that case, `\sffamily` is even more typing, which is precisely what I want to avoid with a solution...